# INotifyPropertyChanged Event Not Calling Event Handler

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I'm doing a bit of MVVM work in SL 4.0, and I've got an event handler that never gets called, despite the event firing, and being non-null.

First, I attach the event handler.  I stepped through this, and notice that after adding the event handler, that PropertyChanged is no longer null, HOWEVER, it's invocationCount is still 0, and it's invocationList is still null.  That's not expected right?

```
node.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnMonitoredDataSourceNodePropertyChanged);
```

Next, I change a property, and call my OnPropertyChanged method, like so:

```
OnPropertyChanged("CheckState");
```

Which fires the method.  I step through that, and upon inspecting the PropertyChanged event, it is NOT NULL which is expected, but, it has an invocationCount of 3, and the invocationList has 4 objects, the last of which is NULL.  That makes no sense to me, there should only be the 1 handler that was previously assigned.  Instead, its some other list, and one that does not include my original handler.

```
public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null) {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

So, PropertyChanged is fired, but my handler is never called.  I've been beating my head against a wall for a couple of hours on this one, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you change the "CheckState" property of correct node instance?

Comment: Yeah it should be the correct instance, that add handler is actually in a loop, so all instances are attached.

Comment: "should be the correct instance" sounds like it isn't.  [Make an object ID](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/04/make-objectid-vstipdebug0015.aspx) for `node`, then check it in `OnPropertyChanged`.

Comment: For testing you can change the "CheckState" property the next line after you register the event.

Comment: @Will, thanks for the tip, it does indeed appear that they are separate instances.  As to why...that's another questions I suppose, but at least that let me confirm they are separate instances.

Comment: Are you binding this property to a UI or within a view model in any way?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, yes, the node collection is a ViewModel property that's bound to a RadTreeView in the UI.  It seems that I've got something handing out instance copies rather than serving the original.

Comment: So, binding generally means the framework subscribes to property notifications to keep the content in the UI up to date--which would explain more than one item in the "invocationCount" (which I assume is really "_invocationCount" and a property of the `MulticastDelegate`)

Comment: @GrantH.: Well, then, that's the answer (for now).  Added so you can close out (heh heh).  Next step is to break in the constructor for the `node` type and check your stack traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code as it appears in the question.  It would suggest that 1) your code is not as is represented here, or 2) the instance you add the listener to in the first part is not the instance you are firing `OnPropertyChanged` on.  Number 2 is my bet.

In order to test this, you should debug your application, placing a breakpoint where you add a listener, and where you are firing `OnPropertyChanged`.

Within Visual Studio, when the first breakpoint is hit, [make an object ID](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/04/make-objectid-vstipdebug0015.aspx) on the instance referenced by the `node` variable.  Let your application continue execution.

When the second breakpoint hits in `OnPropertyChanged`, examine the object ID on `this`.  You'll find out whether or not the instances are the same.

In all things debugging, determine what your assumptions are.  Because that's where your bug lies.

Comment: Thanks @Will, I used this to trace back to the property that was holding the collection.  It seems another developer wrote it to create deep copies instead of simply returning a single instance.  I've got my problem fixed and being able to prove they were separate instances was the key.

Comment: the "make an object ID" link is dead; can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: This article explains how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-tips-and-tricks?view=vs-2019